# Data not adding in database with PDO in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I was working in PHP 5.x for the past 2 years. I just got my PHP version updated to PHP 7.x which uses PDO to add data into the database. Now I have altered my code but the data is not getting added to the database from the User's form whereas it is getting added if I hard code it by changing the `VALUES(' ');` to the value that I want in the SQL QUERY.

Please look into the code and help me with it. Thanks!

```
    <?php
        try{
            $db=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            //echo "Database selected";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['sub'])){
            //echo "going inn";
            $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
            $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
            $mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
            $insert="INSERT INTO users (mailid,password,mobile) VALUES ($email,$password,$mobile)";


            $db->exec($insert);
                echo "New record created successfully";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Just a beginner for now. Will learn this for sure. Thank you.

Comment: Strings in MySQL needs quotes around them (missing in your code), but you should use prepared statements with placeholders (then you don't have to be concerned with my first point).

Comment: @Qirel Do I have to add quotes around the values ?

Comment: @DasaSathyan Look at the first duplicate (about quotes and ticks).